# Parse HTML Within ContentEditable Real Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This one is driving me crazy and Google has got me little help.

**The Question:**
Is it possible to run an real-time parser of Html within a div?

**The Problem:**
When you type inside a contenteditable div Html is not made a 'real' part of the page.
So if I typed

> > `<b>this is a test</b>`

Then it will remain that way, not automatically transform into **this is a test**.

**The Goal:**

> > `<b>this is a test</b>` *to transform into* **this is a test**

The strange part is that if I edit the page through Firebug and insert a tag into the typed Html next to it then it will not transform it into 'real' Html.

It will however do it when a `<br>` is typed **and then** through Firebug a second `<br>` typed next to it. (the second `<br>` will make the typed `<br>` 'real' Html.)

The typed tags are not converted to Html special chars, the are actual tags, but not converting to Html. If you force Html tags through Firebug however then they appear as real Html formatting.

I've tried a lot and I've burnt out of ideas.
I appreciate that ContentEditable is a new technology but any help would be much appreciated!

Apologies if this is incredibly unclear and confusing, it's a real arse to explain.

Comment: For a starter: [Rich text editing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla) ,and something [heavier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you leave the parsing to the browser. Use two elements, one to type into and the other behind to display the rendered output.

Try to utilize transparency for the font in the editor element after the HTML copy (via JS) to the background element.

Comment: Clever. It works, here's a demo folks [http://jsfiddle.net/euF2E/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/euF2E/2/).

Or at least it works there in the demo. I haven't a clue why its not working on my more complex project. I think I'll scrap and start over building on this framework rather than trying to force the change on now.

Thanks Feeela.